# when passed a dictionary into jinja2 template single apostrophe(') is converted into "&#x27;"

Tags: python, django, dictionary, jinja2, apostrophe

JavaScript is throwing an error 'Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token '&''
when debugged in Views.py I got he data with proper Apostrophes.

```
def newEntry(request):
assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
i = 1

for x in lines:
    for line in x:
        cursor.execute("select distinct regionn  FROM [XYZ].[dbo].[Errors] where [Linne] like '%" +line+ "%'")
        region[i] = cursor.fetchall()
        i = i+1

return render(
    request,
    'app/newEntry.html',
    {
        'title': 'New Entry',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
        'lines': lines,
        'regions': region,
    }
 )
```

and here is my JS code

```
var Regions= {{regions}}
 
function changecat(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option>default option here</option>";
    else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in Regions[value]) {
                
            catOptions += "<option>" + categoryId+ "</option>";
            }
        document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance, if this is not a best practice to carry data, suggest me some best process which fills my requirement

Comment: Jinja2 is for HTML templates, not for JavaScript (templates).

Comment: You could set some (invisible) element with a data attribute to your `regions` in your HTML file, then let the JavaScript file pick that up from the HTML file. Or use AJAX with a `fetch` request in your JavaScript file.